# Doxygen Related Pages

Tags: doxygen

I'm looking for a way to customize the title of Related pages ; my locale is french so I get

> Pages associées

But I would like to put other text in place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First create a layout file using

```
doxygen -l
```

then open the generated `DoxygenLayout.xml` with a text editor and look for the line

```
<tab type="pages" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
```

and replace that with

```
<tab type="pages" visible="yes" title="Your Title" intro=""/>
```

and finally mention the layout file in your doxygen configuration file as follows

```
LAYOUT_FILE = DoxygenLayout.xml
```

For more details see https://www.doxygen.org/manual/customize.html#layout

Comment: Thank you very much, I will like Doxygen a little bit more.

Comment: It work but I have trouble with  <tab type="namespaces" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="namespaces" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="namespacemembers" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab> even with visible = no the namespaceMembers is still showing in the left nav.

Comment: I also get trouble with accent, and I can't succeed to put any accent in the layout xml file.

Comment: Link broken. This is likely what the author was attempting to link to: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout

Answer (score 0):

accents: INPUT_ENCODING = "encoding used in your editor" 
Default Visual Studio in North America is CP1252. Doxygen works internally in UTF-8, so it has to convert between the two.